# Using data within an extracted text string for an inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Newbie so please be easy on me.

I have a select statement which returns a text string

```
select [column name]from [table] where [column name] like '%dog%'
```

simple enough, returns a result much like below

random text dog '123' more random text

random text dog '345' more random text

random text dog '723' more random text ...

I am looking to extract the 123, 345, 723 part of the text string which I can kind of do through using

```
Declare @Text Varchar(100);

Set @Text = 'random text dog ''123'' more random text';

Select Left(Substring(@Text, Patindex('%''%', @Text) + 1, Len(@Text) - Patindex('%''%', @Text))
           ,Patindex('%''%', Substring(@Text, Patindex('%''%', @Text) + 1, Len(@Text) - Patindex('%''%', @Text)))- 1) 'Lookup Index'
```

I am then wanting to use the result as part of inner join to another table to return a result along the lines of

```
Lookup Index   Colour
123            Blue
345            Green
723            Orange
```

I just cant seem to tie it all together so any help much appreciated.
Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: SQL Server does not have much built in regex support.  `PATINDEX` might save the day here, but if it doesn't, then consider importing your data in a more normalized form, with the number already extracted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option for you.

Load the parsed data into a temp table, then join that back to your lookup table.   I would be easier and would probably perform better.

Have a look at this.  There's an example with some test data all using temp tables.   You'd obviously need to adjust for your specific tables and requirements:

```
--This will be our table that has the data you want to parse
CREATE TABLE #TestData (
TextColumn nvarchar(1000)
)

--lookup table for colours
CREATE TABLE #LookUp(
LookUpIndex INT
,Colour NVARCHAR(100)
)

--Use a temp table to load the parsed data from #TestData
CREATE TABLE #TestDataParse (
LookUpIndex INT
,TextColumn NVARCHAR(1000)
)

--Load our test data
INSERT INTO [#TestData] ([TextColumn])
VALUES('random text dog ''123'' more random text')
,('random text dog ''345'' more random text')
,('random text dog ''723'' more random text')


--populate our lookup table
INSERT INTO [#LookUp] (
                          [LookUpIndex]
                        , [Colour]
                      )
VALUES(123, 'Blue')
,(345, 'Green')
,(723 , 'Orange')


--Now parse the LookUp number out and load that to our temp table
INSERT INTO [#TestDataParse] (
                                 [LookUpIndex]
                               , [TextColumn]
                             )
SELECT
Left(Substring(TextColumn, Patindex('%''%', TextColumn) + 1, Len(TextColumn) - Patindex('%''%', TextColumn))
           ,Patindex('%''%', Substring(TextColumn, Patindex('%''%', TextColumn) + 1, Len(TextColumn) - Patindex('%''%', TextColumn)))- 1) AS LookUpIndex
           ,[TextColumn]
FROM [#TestData]

--Now we can join that back to the lookup table
SELECT     *
FROM       [#TestDataParse] [a]
INNER JOIN [#LookUp] [b]
    ON [b].[LookUpIndex] = [a].[LookUpIndex];


--Example done
--Drop our #temp tables
DROP TABLE [#LookUp]
DROP TABLE [#TestData]
DROP TABLE [#TestDataParse]
```

or you could skip loading into a temp table and use a sub query to simplify the join back to your lookup table, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT
                Left(Substring(TextColumn, Patindex('%''%', TextColumn) + 1, Len(TextColumn) - Patindex('%''%', TextColumn))
                           ,Patindex('%''%', Substring(TextColumn, Patindex('%''%', TextColumn) + 1, Len(TextColumn) - Patindex('%''%', TextColumn)))- 1) AS LookUpIndex
                           ,[TextColumn]
                FROM [#TestData] a
                ) AS tb
INNER JOIN [#LookUp] b ON [b].[LookUpIndex] = [tb].[LookUpIndex]
```

I'd test each one and see which performs the best for you.

Comment: Many thanks Tim, does exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain but you can do:

```
select t.col, left(v.dogv, charindex('''', v.dogv) - 1)
from (values ('random text dog ''123'' more random text')) t(col) cross apply
     (values (stuff(col, 1, charindex('dog', col) + 4, ''))
     ) v(dogv) 
where col like '%dog%';
```